# Ruby gem Errors

Tags: mysql, ruby, linux

When running a small script which generates tables in a MySQL database, I'm faced with the follow errors.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse':            (/root/.siriproxy/config.yml):
 couldn't parse YAML at line 0 column 0 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:154:in `parse_stream'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:125:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:112:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:229:in `block in load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:229:in `open'
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/psych.rb:229:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.9.9/lib/siriproxy/command_line.r
b:263:in `parse_options'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.9.9/lib/siriproxy/command_line.r
b:38:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.9.9/bin/siriproxy:6:in `new'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@SiriProxy/gems/siriproxy-0.9.9/bin/siriproxy:6:in `<top (re
quired)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@SiriProxy/bin/siriproxy:19:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@SiriProxy/bin/siriproxy:19:in `<main>
```

Any ideas what is causing the error, I have the host , database name, username, and password all supplied in the config file.

Edit: YML File: http://pastie.org/private/pjyua5fczxokfggkxfdbtq

Edit: non comment and blank line file: http://pastie.org/private/n4rwlxhcd4nuon117qt7ag

Comment: can you post the code and the yaml snippet? looks like you have a syntax error in your yaml file..

Comment: maybe this is too obvious... but there's one line in the yaml that looks like it should be a comment, but there's no # before it

Comment: Just checked, it was a copy paste error, there is a # there in the script

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is that the YAML in `/root/.siriproxy/config.yml` is invalid. You can try parsing and validating it here:

- http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: I got two errors. "while scanning Simple key in "<unicode string>" and Could not find expected ":"

Comment: Edited the post to provide the yml file